# Will I be held accountable if I backbite in my head about someone and not say it out

Tags: backbiting

I sometimes get these thought in my head and I may start to try to think about something else will I be held accountable for this as long  as i do not say it out loud

Comment: Allah only sees your intention if your intention is not bad then you won't be held accountable for that

Answer (score 1):

Allah does not hold us accountable for involuntary thoughts as long as we do not speak about it or act upon them.

> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said: “Verily, Allah has pardoned my nation for what occurs within themselves, as long as they do not speak of it or act upon it.”

Also see: https://www.abuaminaelias.com/held-accountable-thoughts/

Allah knows best.